# How to echo php variable in div

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

I'm trying to echo a variable from my php script  inside a div but i'm not getting any result.Here is my code :

```
<?php
session_start();
session_name();

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("bloggers", $con) or die(mysql_error()); 


    $data = "Select * from accountprofile where Username = '" . $_SESSION['Sess_user'] . "' and Password = '" . $_SESSION['Sess_pass'] . "'";

$result = mysql_query($data);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $row['Fname'];
   $row['Username'];
   $row['Password'];

  }
  mysql_close($con);

  ?>
```

and here is my div where i want to display the variable $row['Fname'];

```
<div class="title" style="font-size: 36px;">
    <?php echo $row['Fname']; ?>
</div>
```

Sorry i am just new in html and php .Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're close. Here is your code simplified and corrected:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_name();

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("bloggers", $con) or die(mysql_error()); 

$data = "Select * from accountprofile where Username = '" . $_SESSION['Sess_user'] . "' and Password = '" . $_SESSION['Sess_pass'] . "'";

$result = mysql_query($data);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // You're only getting one row, no need to loop.
mysql_close($con);

 ?>

<div class="title" style="font-size: 36px;">
    <?php echo $row['Fname']; ?>
</div>
```

**FYI**: 
[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 2):

The variable $row is only loop-scope. You're creating this variable inside while and it will only exist there.

Answer (score 0):

@user2047260 remember the variable you whant to display it has to be inside the while loop bellow is the code try it

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    session_name();

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("bloggers", $con) or die(mysql_error()); 


        $data = "Select * from accountprofile where Username = '" . $_SESSION['Sess_user'] . "' and Password = '" . $_SESSION['Sess_pass'] . "'";

    $result = mysql_query($data);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $fname = $row['Fname'];
       $username = $row['Username'];
       $password =$row['Password'];
      ?>
      <div class="title" style="font-size: 36px;">
        <?php echo $fname;
          mysql_close($con);
        }
        ?>
    </div>



        enter code here
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are echoing a variable inside an echo statement, you can do:

```
echo "foo " . $bar . "!";
```

This is called concatenating a string.

If you are looking to use it later on, you can put all of the results into an array by using the following in your while loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $useLaterOn[] = $row;
  }
```

Hopefully this helps :)